# Unable to generate token using smalrye jwt

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus

I'm new to using Quarkus. So I wanted to generate a token using smalrye jwt in my demo app but it keeps failing when i try to make a GET request to this endpoint to get a token `http://localhost:8080/generate-token` with this error message:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: io.smallrye.jwt.build.JwtSignatureException: SRJWT05009: 
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:135)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:90)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.smallrye.jwt.build.JwtSignatureException: SRJWT05009: 
        at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:76)
        at com.beita.TokenService.generateToken(TokenService.java:24)
        at com.beita.TokenService_Subclass.generateToken$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.beita.TokenService_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at com.beita.TokenService_Subclass.generateToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.beita.TokenService_ClientProxy.generateToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.beita.LoginResource.login(LoginResource.java:23)
        at com.beita.LoginResource_Subclass.login$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.beita.LoginResource_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at com.beita.LoginResource_Subclass.login(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRJWT05020: Signing key can not be loaded from: privateKey.pem 
        at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.getSigningKeyFromKeyLocation(JwtSignatureImpl.java:241)
        at io.smallrye.jwt.build.impl.JwtSignatureImpl.sign(JwtSignatureImpl.java:71)
```

This is what I'm doing.

#### application.properties

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=publicKey.pem
smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.pem 
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://example.com/issuer
```

#### TokenService.java

```
@RequestScoped
public class TokenService {
    public String generateToken(){
        return Jwt.issuer("https://example.com/issuer") 
            .upn("johndoe@gmail.com")
            .groups(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("User", "Admin"))) 
            .expiresIn(300L)
            .claim(Claims.birthdate.name(), "2001-07-13") 
        .sign();
    }
}
```

#### TokenResource.java

```
@Path("generate-token")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TokenResource {

    @Inject
    TokenService tokenService;

    @GET
    public Response getToken(){
        String token = tokenService.generateToken();
        return Response.ok(token).build();
    }
}
```

#### LoginResource

```
@Path("/auth")
public class LoginResource {
    
    @GET
    @Path("permit-all")
    @PermitAll
    @javax.ws.rs.Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @Path("roles-allowed") 
    @RolesAllowed({ "User", "Admin" })
    public String helloSecured() {
        return "hello admin or user";
    }
}
```

I have quarkus-smallrye-jwt dependency in pom.xml

#### POM.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have both my privateKey.pem and publicKey.pem in **resources** directory.

#### publicKey.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlivFI8qB4D0y2jy0CfEq
Fyy46R0o7S8TKpsx5xbHKoU1VWg6QkQm+ntyIv1p4kE1sPEQO73+HY8+Bzs75XwR
TYL1BmR1w8J5hmjVWjc6R2BTBGAYRPFRhor3kpM6ni2SPmNNhurEAHw7TaqszP5e
UF/F9+KEBWkwVta+PZ37bwqSE4sCb1soZFrVz/UT/LF4tYpuVYt3YbqToZ3pZOZ9
AX2o1GCG3xwOjkc4x0W7ezbQZdC9iftPxVHR8irOijJRRjcPDtA6vPKpzLl6CyYn
sIYPd99ltwxTHjr3npfv/3Lw50bAkbT4HeLFxTx4flEoZLKO/g0bAoV2uqBhkA9x
nQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

#### privateKey.pem

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a trailing space in this line of your application.properties:

```
smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.pem
```

Remove the space and it should work. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/security-jwt-quickstart/src/main/resources/application.properties

Answer (score 1):

It's for sure your key path. Double check you have the pk file at the right location and that there are no trailing white chars in your application.properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).